# How to make wget trust my self signed certificate (without using --no-check-certificate)?

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, openssl, wget, self-signed-certificate

- Ubuntu 12.04
- OpenSSL 1.0.1 14
- Wget 1.13.4

My setup:

- create our own CA (`our_own_ca.crt`)
- generate a certificate which is signed with the above CA (`graphite.local.crt`)
- Concatenate that cert and the CA cert into a bundle file

Nginx configuration:

```
ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/graphite.local.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/graphite.local.key;
ssl_client_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/our_own_ca_chained.crt;
```

with:

```
our_own_ca_chained.crt = graphite.local.crt + own_own_ca.crt
```

To install this CA into the trusted store, according to `/usr/share/doc/ca-certificates/README.Debian`, I just need to copy it to the `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/`, then run `update-ca-certificates`. Here's the output:

```
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs... 1 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d....
Warning: there was a problem reading the certificate file /etc/ssl/certs/our_own_ca.pem. Message:
  Extensions not allowed in v2 certificate
done.
done.
```

After that, we have something like belows in `/etc/ssl/certs`:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   17 Mar 11 05:27 99ff557c.0 -> our_own_ca.pem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   17 Mar 11 05:27 dc79b3f0.0 -> our_own_ca.pem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   50 Mar 11 05:27 our_own_ca.pem -> /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/our_own_ca.crt
```

then `curl` worked:

curl -I https://graphite.local

```
HTTP/1.1 302 FOUND
Server: nginx
Date: Wed, 11 Mar 2015 05:30:30 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Cookie
Location: https://graphite.local/account/login?next=/
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15768000
```

but `wget` does not:

```
wget https://graphite.local
--2015-03-11 05:31:22--  https://graphite.local/
Resolving graphite.local (graphite.local)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to graphite.local (graphite.local)|127.0.0.1|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify graphite.local's certificate, issued by `xxx':
  Self-signed certificate encountered.
To connect to graphite.local insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
```

I also tried to use the `--ca-certificate` but got the same error.

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

I’d try the `--ca-directory=directory` option:

```
wget --ca-directory=/etc/ssl/certs https://graphite.local
```

From the [wget manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/HTTPS-_0028SSL_002fTLS_0029-Options.html)

> Specifies directory containing CA certificates in PEM format. Each file
> contains one CA certificate, and the file name is based on a hash value
> derived from the certificate. This is achieved by processing a certificate
> directory with the c_rehash utility supplied with OpenSSL. Using
> ‘--ca-directory’ is more efficient than ‘--ca-certificate’ when many
> certificates are installed because it allows Wget to fetch certificates on
> demand.
>
> Without this option Wget looks for CA certificates at the system-specified
> locations, chosen at OpenSSL installation time.

Comment: Doesn't work.  /etc/ssl/certs is the system-specified location.  I also tried manually running `sudo c_rehash` to do the processing WGet wants, but that didn't seem to help either.